# How to decentralize in git Server?

Tags: git

I use git for multi user.
But I don't want this teams same authority for certain project. 
I installed it on Centos.So how do I decentralize for user?
 eg: 
Android team work with project A, and iOS team work with project B. I want only Android team enabled to edit project A . And only iOS team can edit project B.

Thank so much!

Comment: Git doesn't do AAA. The way you handle multi users, authentication and other such details depends on the software you're using to host your repositories and the transports through which you make them available.

Comment: You might need to explain him what `AAA` means.

Comment: [AAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAA_protocol) is authorization, access and accounting which is, generally, what password protected systems provide.

Comment: Thank my friends. I understood this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Git` is already decentralized. Each time a user makes a clone of the repository on his machine, he has the full copy of the whole repository and can be used as a server.